# How do I show git reflog entries in gitkraken

Tags: git

I want to make a cherry-pick command for a specific commit in `git reflog` and show it in gitkraken

b838c88 HEAD@{6}: commit: the user filters wasn't completely finished yet. but the images are now shown for the criminals list and the criminalView

but it wouldn't show up here

[image]

[image]

Comment: What I want is to make that commit / reflog hash : `b838c88` files to be my current branch: `edit-criminals`

Comment: Just because it’s in the reflog doesn’t mean it’s reachable from HEAD.

Comment: So what's should I do @matt

Comment: I don’t know what you want to do. The question was why “it wouldn't show up here”. I’m saying it’s because the diagram on top is the directed log graph from HEAD etc, but the reflog is every commit there’s ever been, including stuff you abandoned when you rebased or cherry picked or whatever you did. So it’s no big surprise if `HEAD@{6}` isn’t in the log diagram.

Comment: If you want see it in the diagram, assign it a branch name, that’s one way; now it’s reachable.

Comment: How do you assign a branch name to it ?

Comment: git branch mybranch b838c88

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209897/discussion-between-thebast-and-matt).

Comment: Then I can checkout on that branch right @matt??

Comment: sure if you like; declaring the branch doesn't automatically check it out - note that no harm can be done by jus declaring the branch, you don't have to use it for anything, you can delete the branch name if you change your mind

Comment: But you could cherry pick it from the command line without bothering to make a branch